# Run a Powershell command from a batch script as administrator

Tags: powershell, batch-file, administrator, elevated

I'm currently writing a batch script that needs to invoke a single Powershell command as administrator.

The batch script is already running in elevated mode.

I have tried the following but it fails miserably... so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

```
powershell -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs} && {irm INSERT WEB ADDRESS HERE}"
```

Any help is very welcome

Comment: HOW is it failing miserably? What's the error message/code? What research have you done using that error message and what else have you tried?

Comment: Like I said to the next poster, the problem lies in the fact that the computer I was using has some protection against Powershell scripts that I didn't know about. I tried the batch I was working on on a computer with a fresh install of Windows and it worked.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered by the OP and the question is unlikely to help anyone else in the future.

Comment: I completely agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the batch script is already running in elevated mode, you don't need
to use Start-Process.

Just execute the command as in: `powershell "irm ..."`.

Comment: That's the big problem... it doesn't seem to work. I just did some additional testing and it seems that the script that it runs on the official server has some issues... No wonder I was having a hard time.

Comment: OK... having to call the IT guys...

Comment: Finally figured out... the computer I was trying to run this in has some protections against Powershell scripts. Tested it against a fresh install and it worked fine. Thanks!